# Azure Active Directory Authentication, can't log in to own app

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am trying to log in with the app (I am owner).

This is the error I get:

> App2 
>   You can't access this application 
>   App2 needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I have already added users inside of Azure for that app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed admin required scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app needs a permission that requires admin consent. For that, an AAD admin can go to the Settings blade for your application, click Required Permissions and click on the Grant Permissions button.

Comment: my app is registered in app developers url and it is enterprise app, which means i don't have settings blade.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add `prompt=admin_consent` to the URL after you get redirected to sign in in Azure AD. The URL would look something like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/....&prompt=admin_consent
```